# Could wrapping Macbook power adaptor with tinfoil be helpful for radiating heat and lowering its temperature quicker?

Tags: thermodynamics

Could wrapping Macbook power adaptor with tinfoil be helpful for radiating heat and lowering its temperature quicker? I sometimes need to use it in a place where there is no AC and it get get excessively hot. Does wrapping it with tinfoil help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are asking whether tin foil  radiates thermal energy more quickly than a (presumably plastic) power adapter.

[Emissivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissivity) is a measure of an object's ability to radiate thermal energy. Metals, such as tin, actually have rather low emissivities, meaning that they are less effective at radiating thermal energy than other materials. A [heat sink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_sink) would be more effective at cooling a warm object. Since metals are excellent thermal conductors, heat is rapidly conducted into the heat sink, which in turn transfers its heat to the atmosphere relatively quickly due to its great surface area.

Having addressed the physics, I also feel obligated to advise you to **use great caution when working with electricity**. If part of an electric appliance gets "excessively hot" as you described in your question, it could be **very dangerous** and you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: For the purpose of cooling the adapter down by wrapping it with tinfoil, it won't work unless somehow I also make its total surface area significantly larger than its original surface area, right?

Comment: Yes; the main point is that it has to do with convection rather than radiation, which will occur more quickly when the surface area is greater. I'm not sure how great the surface area would need to be to outweigh the elimination of heat radiation, though. I doubt that tin foil would be the most effective means for making a heat sink.

Comment: I saw that some of the condensed matter experiment instruments have tin foil (?) wrapped all over, but do not seem to have significantly increased surface areas. What's the purpose for that?

Comment: If the purpose is making the instruments as cool as possible, perhaps it is a reflective material meant to keep radiation from hitting the instruments; i.e., keeping them from heating up rather cooling them down.